# can't find a dependency

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I was building a package from a tutorial [link text](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/whole_body_trajectory) but when I tried doing rosmake I got an error

```
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests trajectory_control_tutorial
[rospack] Error: package/stack trajectory_control_tutorial depends on non-existent package drc_robot_utils
```

I was already working with the drc robot and I know I have it on my disk.

what should I write instead?
thanks

Nachum

Edit\
Now I tried to run a file that I used before from a package that has that  dependency and I am getting this error-

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nachum/joint_control_tutorial/scripts/joint_control12.py", line 3, in <module>
    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('drc_robot_utils')
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
    m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 118, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 157, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 149, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: drc_robot_utils
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/nachum
ROS path [2]=/home/nachum/ros
ROS path [3]=/home/nachum/ros
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
```

what could of happened?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48805/can%27t-find-a-dependency/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both errors mean that the package `drc_robot_utils` was not found. Make sure that it is on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. You can try if it is by running `roscd drc_robot_utils`; that should bring you to the package directory.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-11-27**:
yes that's what it was. how do I permanently put a path on my ros path? I think I put it by echo "source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-11-29**:
Yes, but after that line you should add the path to the packages in your home dir like this: `echo 'export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/nachum/ros/drc_robot_utils:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc`. You can also use [rosws](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws.html) instead.